# How to vectorize the sum? tensor[i,:,:,:] + tensor[i]

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization, pytorch

I want to vectorize the following code:

```
def style_noise(self, y, style):
    n = torch.randn(y.shape)
    for i in range(n.shape[0]):
        n[i] = (n[i] - n.mean(dim=(1, 2, 3))[i]) * style.std(dim=(1, 2, 3))[i] / n.std(dim=(1, 2, 3))[i] + style.mean(dim=(1, 2, 3))[i]
    noise = Variable(n, requires_grad=False).to(y.device)
    return noise
```

I didn't find a way nice way of doing so.

y and style are 4d tensors, say  `style.shape = y.shape = [64, 3, 128, 128]`.

I want to return the noise tensor, `noise.shape = [64, 3, 128, 128]`.

Please let me know in the comments if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is exactly why the `.mean` and `.std` methods come with a `keepdim` parameter. You can make use of this to enable [broadcasting semantics](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) to vectorize things for you:

```
def style_noise(self, y, style):
    n = torch.randn(y.shape)
    n_mean = n.mean(dim=(1, 2, 3), keepdim=True)
    n_std = n.std(dim=(1, 2, 3), keepdim=True)
    style_mean = style.mean(dim=(1, 2, 3), keepdim=True)
    style_std = style.std(dim=(1, 2, 3), keepdim=True)
    n = (n - n_mean) * style_std / n_std + style_mean
    noise = Variable(n, requires_grad=False).to(y.device)
    return noise
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate mean and std for the whole tensor you set no arguments

```
m = t.mean(); print(m) # if you don't set the dim for the whole tensor
s = t.std(); print(s) # if you don't set the dim for the whole tensor
```

Then if your shape is 2,2,2 for instance, create tensors for broadcasting subtract and division.

```
ss = torch.empty(2,2,2).fill_(s)
print(ss)

mm = torch.empty(2,2,2).fill_(m)
print(mm)
```

At the moment `keepdim` is not working as expected when you don't set the `dim`.

```
m = t.mean(); print(m) # for the whole tensor
s = t.std(); print(s) # for the whole tensor

m = t.mean(dim=0); print(m) # 0 means columns mean
s = t.std(dim=0); print(s) # 0 means columns mean

m = t.mean(dim=1); print(m) # 1 means rows mean
s = t.std(dim=1); print(s) # 1 means rows mean

s = t.mean(keepdim=True);print(s) # will not work
m = t.std(keepdim=True);print(m) # will not work
```

If you set a dim as a tuple, then it will return mean for axes, you asked not for the whole.